# Share button will not work with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using [list.js](http://listjs.com/) on a page to filter articles. I am including addThis social share buttons on each of the divs, but for some reason addThis does not work after clicking the pagination controls. It goes away. Can anyone please help me with this? I have included a fiddle below thanks.

- Note cant get addThis to show in fiddle but still hoping someone might know why this isnt working. Thanks!

```js
var monkeyList = new List('pagination-list', {
  valueNames: ['name'],
  page: 3,
  pagination: true
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Articles Pagination Container -->
<div id="pagination-list">

<!-- Articles Pagination Sub Container -->           
<div class="list">
  
   <section>
          <div class="container topmargin name">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 img-margin">
                      <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_d2zn pull-left" data-title="Test1" data-url="http://www.example.com"></div>
                      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../images/misc/crushed_versatility.jpg" alt="Crushed Versatility">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <h1>Test</h1>
                     <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin mi lorem, tristique at facilisis at, pulvinar tincidunt nibh. In blandit metus et metus interdum porttitor sit amet non augue. Morbi euismod pharetra aliquam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque commodo mollis purus, vel auctor leo tempor quis. Sed leo nulla, sollicitudin ut ultricies non, scelerisque vitae tellus. Curabitur blandit diam id fringilla tempus. Praesent egestas, sapien ut placerat feugiat, dui odio viverra ante, quis feugiat enim tortor eu libero.</p>     
                  </div>
                  <br>
              </div>     
          </div>
      </section>

      <section>
          <div class="container topmargin name">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 img-margin">
                     <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_d2zn pull-left" data-title="Test1" data-url="http://www.example.com"></div>
                      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <h1>Test 2</h1>
                     <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin mi lorem, tristique at facilisis at, pulvinar tincidunt nibh. In blandit metus et metus interdum porttitor sit amet non augue. Morbi euismod pharetra aliquam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque commodo mollis purus, vel auctor leo tempor quis. Sed leo nulla, sollicitudin ut ultricies non, scelerisque vitae tellus. Curabitur blandit diam id fringilla tempus. Praesent egestas, sapien ut placerat feugiat, dui odio viverra ante, quis feugiat enim tortor eu libero.</p>
                  </div>
                  <br>
              </div>     
          </div>
      </section>
         
      <section>
          <div class="container topmargin name">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 img-margin">
                     <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_d2zn pull-left" data-title="Test1" data-url="http://www.example.com"></div>
                      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <h1>Test3</h1>
                     <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin mi lorem, tristique at facilisis at, pulvinar tincidunt nibh. In blandit metus et metus interdum porttitor sit amet non augue. Morbi euismod pharetra aliquam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque commodo mollis purus, vel auctor leo tempor quis. Sed leo nulla, sollicitudin ut ultricies non, scelerisque vitae tellus. Curabitur blandit diam id fringilla tempus. Praesent egestas, sapien ut placerat feugiat, dui odio viverra ante, quis feugiat enim tortor eu libero.</p>   
                  </div>
                  <br>
              </div>     
          </div>
      </section>
         
      <section> 
          <div class="container topmargin name">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 img-margin">
                      <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_d2zn pull-left" data-title="Test1" data-url="http://www.example.com"></div>
                      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <h1>Test4</h1>
                     <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin mi lorem, tristique at facilisis at, pulvinar tincidunt nibh. In blandit metus et metus interdum porttitor sit amet non augue. Morbi euismod pharetra aliquam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque commodo mollis purus, vel auctor leo tempor quis. Sed leo nulla, sollicitudin ut ultricies non, scelerisque vitae tellus. Curabitur blandit diam id fringilla tempus. Praesent egestas, sapien ut placerat feugiat, dui odio viverra ante, quis feugiat enim tortor eu libero.</p>      
                  </div>
                  <br>
              </div>     
          </div>
      </section>
         
      <section>
          <div class="container topmargin name">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_d2zn pull-left" data-title="Test1" data-url="http://www.example.com"></div>
                      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="">
                  
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <h1>Test 5</h1>
                     <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin mi lorem, tristique at facilisis at, pulvinar tincidunt nibh. In blandit metus et metus interdum porttitor sit amet non augue. Morbi euismod pharetra aliquam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque commodo mollis purus, vel auctor leo tempor quis. Sed leo nulla, sollicitudin ut ultricies non, scelerisque vitae tellus. Curabitur blandit diam id fringilla tempus. Praesent egestas, sapien ut placerat feugiat, dui odio viverra ante, quis feugiat enim tortor eu libero.</p>
                  </div>
                  <br>
              </div>     
          </div>
      </section>
    
</div>
<!-- Articles Pagination Sub Container End --> 

<!-- Pagination Controls -->
<section>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="pagination"></div>
          </div>
      </div>     
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Pagination Controls End -->
    
</div>
<!-- Articles Pagination Container End -->
```

Comment: Does your page url change with pagination ? AddThis uses page url's to point to correct page when shared, if you paginated page does not have url's changing on browser it may be difficult to share them...

Comment: no but i am just setting the data title and url for each div. it works with the pagination turned off